# Bad rendering with shadows and facets

Tags: rendering, subdivision-surface

Its not the first time I render a model but now I have 2 problems as you can see.
The "shadows" on the door for example and the spoiler of the car which is not smooth (even if smooth button is selected).
Catmull-Clark modifier is on with 2 subdivisions on rendering.

What's wrong?
thanx

[image: Render]

[image: Mesh]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pictures given, it can bee seen that the door is a separate object, the reason the there is no smooth transition between the door and the rest of the car is because there is no shared geometry. I would join the two objects together and use loop tools to bridge the geometry together

To enable loop tools go to file ->user preferences -> add on -> loop tools

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want the door to be separated from the body. The shadow starts at the edge of the door ang go to the rear. But i don't know why.

Comment: Could you add a picture of the wireframe view of the bottom left  front bumper (where the weird shading is)

Comment: I added a picture.

Comment: I actually meant the object mode wireframe xD

Comment: I found the issue for the front bumper. "use modifier during render" was disable in the Subdivision Surface Modifier!!!